# I installed bootstrap-sass in Visual Studio 2022 but it is not included in the project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2022, bootstrap-sass

I installed `bootstrap sass` in `Visual Studio 2022` but it is not included in the project

[image]

Comment: 1: "asp.net 2022" doesn't exist. 2: ASP.NET != ASP.NET Core. 3: NuGet shouldn't be used for web UI packages. 4: Did you do some basic troubleshooting like looking at the warnings?

Comment: Bootstrap-Sass and jQuery, etc... in Visual Studio 2022. Whatever I am installing from nuget, it gets installed but is not visible. where does the install go

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have the same issue. Using NuGet was recommended by Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/download/

Those files in the explorer are **links** to the actual files which can be found in C:\Users\< user >\.nuget\packages\bootstrap\5.1.3\contentFiles\any\any\wwwroot\css\ and \js\

However, they are not visible in the project wwwroot directory and I get a 404 error.

I ended up just skipping this all together and using the CDN method.

Comment: I am already using CDS method.
Thanks for giving your valuable time.

Comment: How is that an answer to the question?

Answer (score 5):

It's been over a year but it might still be helpful for others. Visual Studio changed the way of installing the client libraries. Instead of using the NuGet Packages tool, it changed to use the Client-side Libraries tool. To install Bootstrap, you right-click on the project -> Add -> Client-side Library...-> Provider: unpkg, Library: bootstrap -> then select select either all files or the folders you only need, such as scss folder only. -> Install

Answer (score 0):

Adding more info to the answer by LeoX made on Apr 25, 2023, about NuGet and Client Side Libraries.

I followed the instructions in Visual Studio 2022 and the library didn't get installed. I was missing the following step.

Go to your libman.json file

Delete the following lines. See bolded lines, also DELETE THE COMA after the provider name.

{
"version": "1.0",
"defaultProvider": "cdnjs"**,
"libraries": [
{
"library": "bootstrap@5.1.3",
"destination": "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/"
}
]**
}

After I did that, I was able to Add --> Client Side Library --> Bootstrap and everything got installed/added to my project. :)